# First-of-type and Last-of-type for CSS trick causes rounded edges to appear shorter in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors, cross-browser

Using the `radio+label` trick for making custom styling of radio buttons, the first-of-type and last-of-type appears different in at least Internet Explorer 11 (IE11). The bottom part of the first and last of each appears to be cut off or shortened, according to the background shown.  If I remove or comment out all the `first-of-type` and `last-of-type` selectors, it displays default squared buttons just fine.  Screenshots below.

CSS that's affected:

```
/* Trick for custom styling of radio buttons */
.spr-status [type="radio"] + label,
.spr-field  [type="radio"] + label {
  margin: 0 1px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#444;
  background-color:#EEE;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.spr-status [type="radio"] + label:first-of-type,
.spr-field  [type="radio"] + label:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
}

.spr-status [type="radio"] + label:last-of-type,
.spr-field  [type="radio"] + label:last-of-type {
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}
```

How it should look: Current version of Chrome & Firefox:
[image: How it should look: Current version of Chrome & Firefox]

How it looks in IE (shortened background on first and last of type):
[image: How it looks in IE (shortened background on first and last of type)]

No IE11 (or any tested browser) issues when not using rounded corners with first-of-type and last-of-type
[image: No IE11 (or any tested browser) issues when not using rounded corners with first-of-type and last-of-type]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for this method again, I noticed that I forgot to explicitly put `display` in the first selector.

The solution was to add `display:inline-block`, as below:

```
.spr-status [type="radio"] + label,
.spr-field  [type="radio"] + label {
  display:inline-block;
...
```